# Why is the expectation of a trace equal to the trace of the expectation?

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, proof-writing

Some textbooks use the property $$\mathbb{E}\left[\operatorname{tr}\left(X\right)\right]=\operatorname{tr}\left(\mathbb{E}\left[X\right]\right)$$
But why? I would really appreciate it if someone could prove this.

Comment: Taking the trace is a linear operation (it's essentially a sum). So you can use linearity of expectations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am assuming that $X$ is a random matrix, with finite dimensions. Then
$$
\textrm{tr}\ X=\sum_i X_{ii}.
$$
Hence, the claim follows by [linearity of expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Linearity), since
$$
\mathbb E(\textrm{tr}\ X)=\mathbb E\sum_i X_{ii}=\sum_i \mathbb E X_{ii}=\sum_i (\mathbb E X)_{ii}=\textrm{tr}\ (\mathbb EX).
$$